# Multilevel dict to return None when key not found

Tags: python

I have to parse a JSON that is extremely variable.

Let's say that in its most complete form it's like this:

```
{
   "a":{
      "b":{
         "c":4,
         "d":[
            "foo",
            "bar"
         ]
      },
      "e":"fubar"
   },
   "f":"hello there"
}
```

However any one of those keys may be missing.

How can I convert the dict that json.loads will return in something that will return None if I try to access any missing key? I know that dict.get() has that behaviour but that only works in a single level dict.

Comment: You can chain calls to `get` just like you can chain `[]`s. `d.get('a', {}).get('b', {}).get('c', None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a value in `.get()` that will return if the key is not found, it does not have to return `None`.

`dict_.get('first_key', dict()).get('second_key')`